# Understanding Confidence Intervals to Reach Significance

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval

My question is in regards to whether you can use confidence intervals to claim statistical significance?  For example, if I calculate the CI at 95% for weekly sales to be between $100–$200 and one week I reach sales of $250, is this a significant result?  If not, how exactly would you describe the effect in relation to the CI we calculated?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you can interpret CI coverage in terms of significance testing, and sometimes you cannot depending on the specific test and null hypothesis. There's a literature on the issues that arise which is sometimes termed 'visual hypothesis testing', a brief bibliography of which is presented here (I might start with the article by Geoff Cumming):

Afshartous, D. and Preston, R. (2010). [Confidence intervals for dependent data: Equating non-overlap with statistical significance](https://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/699a/f5d51b6c0d92754b5008cd3aa88e4dc0000b.pdf). *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis*, 54(10):2296–2305.

Browne, R. H. (1979). [On visual assessment of the significance of a mean difference](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2530259). *Biometrics*, 35(3):657–665.

Cumming, G. (2009). [Inference by eye: reading the overlap of independent confidence intervals](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.3471/full). *Statistics In Medicine*, 28(2):205–220.

Goldstein, H. and Healy, M. J. R. (1995). [The graphical presentation of a collection of means](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2983411). *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series A (Statistics in Society)*, 158(1):175– 177.

Payton, M. R., Miller, A., and Raun, W. (2000). [Testing statistical hypotheses using standard error bars and confidence intervals](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00103620009370458). *Communications in soil science and plant analysis*, 31(5):547–551.

Payton, M. E., Greenstone, M. H., and Schenker, N. (2003). [Overlapping confidence intervals or standard error intervals: What do they mean in terms of statistical significance?](http://www.bioone.org/doi/full/10.1673/031.003.3401) *Journal of Insect Science*, 3(34):1–6.

Smith, R. W. (1997). [Visual hypothesis testing with confidence intervals](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi22/STATS/PAPER270.PDF). In Proceedings of the Twenty-Second Annual SAS® Users Group International Conference.

Tryon, W. W. and Lewis, C. (2008). [An inferential confidence interval method of establishing statistical equivalence that corrects Tryon’s (2001) reduction factor](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/met/13/3/272/). *Psychological Methods*, 13(3):272–277.

Comment: I used to believe confidence intervals were simply concatenated significance tests. From your answer I now believe it was merely because I was dealing with two-tailed t-distributions.

Comment: @lucasfariaslf Confidence intervals are a form of statistical inference which—speaking loosely—provides a range of plausible estimates (e.g., "estimates may be as low as *lower bound*, or as high as *upper bound*"). By contrast, hypothesis tests are a form of statistical inference which provide *evidence against a null hypothesis*, and are more like procedures for making decisions about an image of the world (e.g., "we found evidence that the world *does not* look like $H_{0}$, so we conclude the world looks like $H_{A}$").

Comment: The term "significant" often gets in the way of clear statistical thinking.. Try rewriting your question without using that word and with more specifics about what question you are trying to answer.